# Gathering a certain image from a website using a keyword (Dailybooth)

Tags: php, image, url

I'm working on this project at the moment and I need to gather the main image from a url that is given from DailyBooth. I've made a simple function that gathers info from inside 2 parameters from a given website.
However, I would prefer to search for a url with a certain keyword (I.E image urls with word large in (which is only one on the given page)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a look at [PHP Simple DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

After grabbing the page in question, search for the `#main_picture_container`, and the image within;

```
foreach($html->find('div[id=main_picture_container]') as $maindiv)
{
       foreach($maindiv->find('img') as $img)
       {
             // do something...
       }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this is a very nice little package.